# How can I rewrite README.md from my repository withc each commit that I will do?

Tags: git, github, version-control, github-actions, versioning

I have a question regarding the README.md generation.
I have a repository with next structure:

```
|- books (folder)
|- readme.md
|- index.py
```

index.py regenerates the readme.md file creating a list with all the books inside the folder, and creating links to the book.
What I am looking for right now is just a way to execute index.py each time that I did a commit into the repo, to update automatically the readme.md file.

I was able to do it executing the code from an external server. I read the commits, and if there is a new one, execute the code and push the code, but I don't want to depend of an external server.

Also, I take a look on the Actions, but not discover any action that allows me to do it.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: should `readme.md`  be a part of the commit

Comment: have you looked at githooks? all you need here is a pre-commit githook

Comment: Why not creating a workflow running the `index.py` file on each push to the repo (except for the path `README.md` to avoid infinite loop) and then committing the updated README.md file to the repository using git commands on a step through the shell?

Comment: I agree with @user3159253's question. If the readme change is in its own separate commit, make sure you don't get caught in an infinite loop. Just have the hook/job be smart enough to *not* run for commits that only change readme.md.